# Problem creating mock method for "core/store" with ecomdev phpunit

Tags: ecomdev-phpunit, unit-tests

I'm trying to mock this method: **getCurrentCurrency()** from **"core/store"** (Mage_Core_Model_Store) in my unit test. Just a simple stub, nothing more.

```
private function _stubGetCurrentCurrency() {
    $mock = $this->getModelMock(
        'core/store',
        array(
            'getCurrentCurrency'
        )
    );
    $mock
        ->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getCurrentCurrency')
        ->will($this->returnCallback(array($this, 'signal')));
    $this->replaceByMock(
        'singleton',
        'core/store',
        $mock
    );
}

function signal() {
    echo "\n- Signal invoked -\n";
}
```

However it doesn't seem to work for me - when I do **$this->_stubGetCurrentCurrency();** I don't see the **signal()** is being called at all. I've ascertained that the original method is being invoked instead. Looks like I'm missing something, but I can't find what's wrong.

I also have stubs for "sales/order_invoice" canCapture() and "salesrule/observer" addProductAttributes() in that test - they are instantiated in the same manner and both work perfectly fine.

Can anyone point out my miss?
Thank you.

Comment: Apparently, the problem is core/store object is instantiated by store_collection by real class name (not by alias) for performance. So the mocking with aliases does not work. But this is not the only problem it seems, you have to re-init the store as well, and this brings another problem with discarding your fixture data after test. I'll post when I have the 100% working solution.

Comment: The type parameter of `replaceByMock()` should be 'model', not 'singleton'. However, I couldn't get this to work neither, even with `$this->app()->reinitStores()`. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I ended up mocking `core/store`, it may work for you!

```
class Mage_Core_Model_Store_Stub extends Mage_Core_Model_Store
{
    public function setCurrentCurrencyCode($currency)
    {
        return $this->setData('current_currency_code', $currency);
    }
    public function getCurrentCurrencyCode()
    {
        return $this->getData('current_currency_code');
    }
}

$coreStore = new Mage_Core_Model_Store_Stub();
$coreStore->setCurrentCurrencyCode($currency);
Mage::app()->getStore($coreStore)->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
```